# 8086 Assembly time print interruption

Tags: printing, x86-16

I want to print the system time in hh:mm format, and store it in `AM` array or `PM` array, depending on what time it is.
Here is what i have:

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    hour db ?
    min db ?
    AM db ?
    PM db ?
data ends

code segment
start:
    mov ah, 2Ch     ;
    int 21h
    mov hour, CH
    mov min, CL
```

I know that function `2Ch` returns `CH = hour`. `CL = minute`. `DH = second`. `DL = 1/100` seconds

How can i use this, to print the current time ? 
Any ideas?
(I am using TASM, TLINK, and turbo debugger)

Comment: You asking how to print number to std out?

Comment: If i could print on screen the current time, in "hh:mm" format, when i execute the *.exe file, i would be happy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look up some kind of system call for writing to a console (I think there are actually some BIOS routines that do this if you're not running under a mainstream OS) or link your code with a library that provides a printing function and invoke that.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you printing string: [An Introduction to Assembly Instructions](http://prism2.mem.drexel.edu/~rares/asm3.htm)
That's how you printing decimal number: [Print decimal in 8086 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113060/print-decimal-in-8086-emulator)